# #define in C: what is happening

Tags: c, area

Can someone explain what is happening at every step?
I know the final output is 140.5, but I am unsure why that is. What is happening at each line that is resulting in 140.5?

```
#define PI 3.1
#define calcCircleArea(r) (PI * (r) * (r))
#define calcCylinderArea(r,h) (calcCircleArea(r) * h)
int main() {
    double i = calcCylinderArea(3.0,5.0 + 1); printf("%g", i);
}
```

Comment: Run `cc -E -o preprocessed.c source.c` and look at the result.

Comment: First remember (or learn) that macros are *expanded* at compile-time. Basically what's happening is that a macro "call" is replaced by the body of the macro. Now to understand what's happening, please try to expand the macros yourself, one by one, until you have a single non-macro expression. Note that most compiler have an option to do this for you (show you the preprocessed file).

Comment: You have a bug: Because `calcCylinderArea` is a CPP _macro_, and because you pass it `5.0 + 1` for `h`, [where `x` is `calcCircleArea` ...] you'll get [effectively] `(x * 5.0) + 1` instead of `(x * (5.0 + 1)`, which is what you want. This is because multiplication has a higher precedence than addition and so the multiply will be performed first and _then_ the addition will be applied to that. Add parentheses around `h` [as you did for `r` in `calcCircleArea`. That is: `#define calcCylinderArea(r,h) (calcCircleArea(r) * (h))`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! I understand this code is not great and there is a bug. I was not looking for a fix, but more of a conceptual understanding of what was happening. Rather, I was trying to understand what is happening at every level during this process (I am new to #define). I appreciate your comments and your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Step 0

```
calcCylinderArea(3.0,5.0+1)
```

## Step 1

```
(calcCircleArea(3.0)*5.0+1)
```

notice that it is not `(5.0+1)`.
Problem begins here.

## Step 2

```
((PI*(3.0)*(3.0))*5.0+1)
```

## Step 3

```
((3.1*(3.0)*(3.0))*5.0+1)
```

Comment: Please refrain from editorializing.

Comment: @zwol Thank you for your suggestion. Is the "another example" part you are commenting? If yes, I will fix it and avoid doing that again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

calcCylinderArea(3.0,5.0 + 1) is evaluated as:
calcCircleArea(3.0) * 5.0 + 1 which is evaluated as:
PI * 3.0 * 3.0 * 5.0 + 1 
which is 140.5

multiplication is done before addition

To fix the issue change the line to:
calcCylinderArea(3.0,(5.0 + 1))
so that the addition is done first.

Comment: It's the macro definition that should be changed, not the callsite.