# Unexpected output in expression that uses macros

Tags: c, macros, output, preprocessor

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRODUCT(x) (x * x)

int main()
{
    int i = 3, j, k, l;
    j = PRODUCT(i + 1);
    k = PRODUCT(i++);
    l = PRODUCT(++i);
    printf("%d %d %d %d", i, j, k, l);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to comprehend why the output is:

```
7 7 12 49.
```

Is there any error in macro or some other problem?

Comment: Using this macro with `i++` results in undefined behavior.  Anything can happen.

Comment: Macros are evil.  Try this:  `j = PRODUCT("Hello");`  Functions are so much better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#define in C: what is happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491522/define-in-c-what-is-happening)

Comment: @user12986714 your reference has no link with the current problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your macro is incorrect. The following expression:

```
PRODUCT(i+1)
```

will expand to

```
(i+1 * i+1)
```

which is `2*i+1`.

Your macro should be:

```
#define PRODUCT(x) ((x)*(x))
```

I strongly suggest you stop using macros for this sort of thing. You could easily write this as a function:

```
int product(int x)
{
  return x * x;
}
```

Note that this will only work for the example I gave. If you try

```
PRODUCT(i++)
```

you will get

```
( (i++) * (i++) )
```

which invokes undefined behaviour, as this expression lacks a sequence point between the 2 increments.

Answer (score 6):

Your code has undefined behavior, operations in `i`:

```
k=PRODUCT(i++);
l=PRODUCT(++i);
```

[lack a sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3575350/6865932).

As for:

```
j=PRODUCT(i+1);
```

It expands to `i+1*i+1` which is `i+i+1` which is `7`. I assume it's not the expected result, in the future also include that in your question.